# How to influence class generation of group declarations with XJC

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2, xjc

We have the following problem. We try to generate Java code from XSD files that contain group declarations and multiple group references to these group declarations. Here a simplified version:

```
<xs:group name="Information">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute name="updated" type="xs:boolean"/>
          </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
 </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="Address">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="Information" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Customer">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
       <xs:group ref="Information"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The main points are:

- Each of these elements is defined in its own file
- The same group `Information` is references twice
- There is no separate type for the group
- There is also no separate type for the `Name` element inside the group
- We cannot change the XSD file

The problem we face now is that xjc generates *non-deterministically* depending on the machine where we build, sometimes the type `Address.Name` and sometimes the type `Customer.Name`, because the `Name` element is a complex type and requires a type.

Is there any way to tell xjc to always generate the same type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Customize the anonymous complex type with the `jaxb:class` binding and specify the class name.
- Use `<jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>` to generate inner classes on the top level instead.

A combination of these two will give you a predictable class.

Comment: Thanks that did it! Using localScoping="toplevel" immediatly solved the problem. However, other types now had conflicts, which I then could solve using class bindings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `-episode` [command line option of XJC](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.1.4/docs/xjc.html). It is primarily meant for compilation in multiple steps, but I think it basically "dumps decisions" taken by XJC during a compilation into a (binding) configuration file. If you are lucky, you find suitable settings related to the `Name` element/type in the episode file which you can copy into your binding configuration file to make XJC behave deterministically.

Comment: Interesting! However, the generated file did not contain the Name type.